# How do I add a jQuery popup box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to add a jQuery pop up box to my web page (instead  ordinary javascript alert box) and I found out a sample code from  [this site](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/)http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/

Can anyone tell me  from where I much add `$("#trigger_id").leanModal();` code  into my HTML code or given JavaScript file?

Comment: Ane example of your code would probably help.

Comment: you add it directly to your page where you want to place it on the link.

Comment: uhh, not exactly? the code he posted is javascript so it needs to be enclosed in <script> tags, or in a separate javascript file that is referenced in the html file.

Comment: @ Placeholders_in_use   I wanted a pop up box appear when user submit the form so if I use a submit button do I have to add that code to 'OnSubmit ' event

Comment: It depends.  I'm guessing that the library you linked is an included javascript file that you need in your html.  The call you put in your question will execute the alert separately of the onsubmit.

Comment: So, I just took a brief look at the site you linked.  this is basically to be used in conjunction with a modal dialog trigger, so it's not a direct substitute for alert();  you need to have your own modal dialog box constructed to use this.

Comment: Can anyone give me a good link where i can add a popup box to my webpage I'm not good in jQuery but instead normal javascript aler tbox I need a nice one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something alike:

```
<a id="trigger1" href="#" name="modalDialog1">click to show message</a>

<div id="modalDialog1">Some message</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#trigger1").leanModal();
</script>
```

Basically the name of the anchor tag should be the same with the id attribute of the div element that is going to be displayed as a dialog.

The rest is CSS formatting, which I believe you should be able to do, based on the information of the site you have referenced to in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), it's not the same one but your problem you have can be answered here on this page where is whole source code for this dialog.